# Why is my JavaScript code with arrays not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve the CodeWars Kata: Zeros and Ones.
My code solves over 1800 of the Attempt tests and fails just over 100.
My problem is that I cannot see the test data because it is so large. 
To see the test data in other katas I can use a console.log statement.
But, the test data in this challenge is too large. I get a list of the first part of an input array followed by "and 400 more items."

Below is a description of the kata and my code along with some test cases.
I have tried to create test cases that fail when my code runs them; but, I am unable create any that fail.

- Is my logic sound? Am I missing anything in the logic?
- Can you supply a test case that would fail? (That would be better to help me learn as I would have to analyze my code to fix it.)

> Given an array containing only zeros and ones, find the index of the
>   zero that, if converted to one, will make the longest sequence of
>   ones. For instance, given the array...
>   [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1], ...replacing the zero at
>   index 10 (counting from 0) forms a sequence of 9 ones. Your task is to
>   write the function replaceZero() that determines where to replace a
>   zero with a one to make the maximum length sub sequence. Note: If the
>   are multiple results, return the last [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1] //=> 5 The
>   array will always contain zeros and ones.

```
function replaceZero(arr){

var highestCt = 0;
var returnIdx = 0;

var onesCt = 0;
var currentHighOnesCt = 0;

function countOnes(currentIZ){ // The input should be the current index of the ZERO.
  for(var j = currentIZ - 1; j >= 0; j--){ // Go backwards until a zero is found, or to the beginning of the array.
    if(arr[j] === 1){
      onesCt = onesCt + 1;
    }
    else { // if arr[j] === 0
      break;
    }
  }
  for(var k = currentIZ + 1; k < arr.length; k++){ // Go forwards to a zero or the end of the array.
    if(arr[k] === 1){
      onesCt = onesCt + 1;
    }
    else { // if arr[k] === 0
      break;
    }
  }
  if(onesCt >= currentHighOnesCt){
    currentHighOnesCt = onesCt;
    returnIdx = currentIZ;
  }
  onesCt = 0;
}

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++)
  if(arr[i] === 1 && arr[i + 1] === 0 && arr[i + 2] === 1){
    countOnes(i + 1); // Send the index of the ZERO.
  }

// console.log("returnIdx: " + returnIdx);

return returnIdx;
}

/*
replaceZero([0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]); // 5
replaceZero([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]); // 6
replaceZero([1,1,1,1,0,1]); // 4
*/
replaceZero([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]); // 9
replaceZero([1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]); // 5

/*
replaceZero([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]); // 6
replaceZero([0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]); // 8
replaceZero([0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]); // 15
replaceZero([1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]); // 10;
replaceZero([1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]); // 5;
replaceZero([1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]); // 6);
*/
```

Comment: This question would be a better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I read the rules at Code Review. It stated that the code have to be working. My code is not working.

Comment: can you provide a link to the kata?

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a00a8b5ffe75f8888000080

Comment: I thought it would be a good exercise and took a different approach to a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/95ep1v8h/) it does not solve your problem but I thought I'd throw my solution out there..

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed. I will look at your solution. I do like looking at other's solutions to learn. It is sometimes frustrating because they are usually much more efficient than my own. While I can solve most katas so far at Code Wars, I am using brute force. I think it is because I don't know all the JS tools well enough to think more creatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so, i'm not actually going to refactor your code, but this might help you:

- Why do you assume the `Zero` you have to change is in between two `Ones`?
  your if statement is flawed in that matter.

your code:

```
if(arr[i] === 1 && arr[i + 1] === 0 && arr[i + 2] === 1){ //WHY IN BETWEEN??
  countOnes(i + 1); // Send the index of the ZERO.
}
```

- Having the above in mind, the following scenarios will fail:

Code:

```
replaceZero([0,0,0,0,0,0,1]); // 0
replaceZero([0,0,0,0,0,1,1]); // 0
replaceZero([0,0,0,0,1,1,1]); // 0
//.. and so on
//Also
replaceZero([1,1,1,1,1,0,0]); // 0
replaceZero([1,1,1,1,0,0,0]); // 0
```

and don't be surprised if there is a test for `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` in this case the last index in the array is the expected answer.

Comment: Good. Thanks. I don't want you to rewrite it. I just want to know where it is failing or why so I can work it out. Hmm...OK. I never considered test cases where there wouldn't be a 0,1,0 sequence. But, that is never stated in the kata description. It is my fault for not considering that possibility. I will rework my code for that situation and get back to this post. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, you will encounter quite a few katas that do not explicitly explain every scenario, sometimes it can be challenging but I think these kind of problems really help you improve your skills. also don't forget to upvote the answer if you've found it helpful. good luck!

Comment: While I haven't solved everything yet, your suggestion led me to the issues in my code:
- There are test cases were the longest string of ones is at the end of the array. This string is longer than any combination of strings of ones separated by a single zero.

- There are also test cases where there are string of ones surrounded by two or more zeros that are longer than any combination of strings of ones separated by a single zero.

I am not sure if there are any strings of ones at the beginning of a test array followed by two or more zeros. But, I should probably account for this.

Comment: Just after I commented to your answer, I went to CodeWars. I tried entering this:

console.log(arr.toString());

It was just messing around hoping that the consolidated array to a string would display the full test input array. I didn't get all the test cases as the buffer filled up. But, I had plenty of test cases to view that failed. And, your suggestions led me to look for specific things in the test cases.
So, in fact, your answer was the one that will eventually solve my issue once I get the code to allow for all the possibilities listed above.

Thanks.